# Storing multiple SharedPreferences based on days in a calendar

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

Hi I want to store and retrive temperature readings of each day. I am fairly new to Android and for this purpose I have used a service. First, I check if there are any previously stored shared preferences and load them.  The snippet is as follows:

```
public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if(prefs.contains("old_data")){
            SharedPreferences prefs2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String json = prefs2.getString("old_data","");
            TypeToken<ArrayList<Float>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Float>>() {};
            ArrayList<Float> oldValues = new Gson().fromJson(json,token.getType());
            LineChartActivity.PlaceholderFragment.generateValues(oldValues) ;}


             isRunning = true;
    }
```

Later, I load the new data using the following snippet :

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

       //code to retrieve temperature
            String json = new Gson().toJson(tempValueC);    
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            prefs.edit().putString("old_data",json).commit();              


}
```

The above code stores the temperature readings and later load the previously stored reading and overwrites new readings.

I want to store temperature readings of each day separately (I have included a calendar). So, I am searching for a suitable method to proceed. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: SharedPreferences are unique key-value. Therefore you'll be overwriting the content all the time. What you want is most likely a database : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html where you can store in a table a date along with the temperature

Comment: I disagree @NicolasSimon. What you can do is set the keys of your entries in SharedPreferences by date and additional data, for example 20160418_old, 20160418_current, 20160418_new etc, and it can very much be more complex. I'd avoid using database as far as I can, as SharedPreferences work much much much faster even if loaded with huge amount of data.

Comment: SharedPrefs will work as key-value. Therefore you'll need to store somewhere else each key you've been using for your SharedPref. Where are you going to store them?

Comment: @NicolasSimon No you don't, you can develop a logic (which is the essence of coding), in this case for example [date]_[string]_[numberOrString]_etc, and always get the data as per that logic. And it will take less storage, and it will work much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use SharedPreferences for this and don't want to use database...

You can do like that....

```
String todayDate;
prefs.edit().putString(todayDate+"old_data",json).commit();
```

Every time when you json return data and todayDate will be change then your   temperature readings will store for each day separately.

Comment: SharedPrefs will work as key-value. Therefore you'll need to store somewhere else each key you've been using for your SharedPref. Where are you going to store them?

Comment: @NicolasSimon As I said, you don't need to store anything, as long as you use common sense and logic (which is the essence of coding), in this case for example [date]_[string]_[numberOrString]_etc, and always get the data as per that logic. And it will take less storage, and it will work much faster.

Comment: @NicolasSimon....As you said "SharedPrefs will work as key-value". So all values will save in key-value format in this case also and for storing vaule android creates a xml file in which all values saves in key-value format.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `StringSet` to SharedPreferences. (only for android versions above HONEYCOMB)

[This library](https://github.com/viralypatel/Android-SharedPreferences-Helper) will make the usage of `SharedPreference` class simpler for you.

Example of usage:

```
// putStringSet is supported only for android versions above HONEYCOMB
SharedPreferencesHelper sph; 
sph = new SharedPreferencesHelper(this); //this will use default shared preferences
Set name = new HashSet();
name.add("Viral");
name.add("Patel");
sph.putStringSet("name", name)
```